# how to put elements in fixed positions in a ScrollView

Tags: android, user-interface

I want to create a kind of scroll view that its elements are fixed in the middle of the view and the user needs to move the element a considerable amount or the view bounces back to the middle of the view.

I tried to use several `overscrolls` next to each other and create a bounce effect but the result wasn't pretty.

is there any library for this kind of scroll view? or there is any way to do this?

Comment: it think you should give recycler view or a view pager a try, for scroll behaviour you can use on scroll listner.

Comment: If you elaborate more and give an example with an image it would be easy to answer. But, by the details you have provided view pager is a nice way to achieve what you want to do

Answer (score 0):

If I understand this correctly, you have a fixed element fixed in the middle of the viewport. You want the user to move the element some fixed amount, say X.
If moved less than X, it should go back to the middle of the viewport?

If yes, then you should definitely look into [http://bouncejs.com](http://bouncejs.com/).

Also, this might interest/help you: https://scrollmagic.io/examples/